# Prevent accidental mousewheel control change when scrolling form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, mousewheel

So imagine you've got a combobox on a form, and the form is big enough that it has scroll bars. As the user is using the mousewheel to scroll down the form, the cursor happens to fall over a combobox, which intercepts the mousewheel and changes it's value instead of the form continuing to scroll.

I'm looking at options to prevent that accidental value change, but still retain the mousewheel functionality on the combobox.

At the moment I'm thinking of doing something like finding out how many milliseconds have elapsed since the last form scroll event and the combobox mousewheel event firing, and ignoring the mousewheel event if it's less than a certain amount of time, but I feel like that's probably a horrible way of doing it, and there are probably more elegant solutions.

I don't particularly want to disable the mousewheel entirely in the combobox, I'd like the user to still be able to hover then use the wheel to change the value, but I need to figure out when this is intentional rather than part of a scroll.

Also I'm just using a combobox as an example here, the same applies to NumericUpDowns and other controls.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This is just my opinion, but I don't think you want to mess with the way things normally work in a Windows form. If the values in those combo boxes are that important to protect from accidental change, perhaps you could add a `locked` checkbox next to them that disables/enables any change?

Comment: I agree, don't change standard windows behavior. Instead ask yourself why your users only noticed this with your software. Is your form too large? Would it be better broken up with tabs or expanders, or separated into smaller forms?

Comment: `ComboBoxes` don't usually scroll when the mouse cursor just happens to move over their ClientArea. You need to *Enter* them before they scroll. If the Form has `AutoScroll = true`, the Form takes the `MouseWheel` event. Only when a focusable control is entered, it will take precedence over the Form's scrolling.